# Keyboard application in JavaFX that when I hit the enter button on keyboard it does an event

Tags: button, javafx, keyboard, key-bindings

I have made a keyboard in javaFX and can either type on my keyboard or push the buttons with my mouse but the enter button on my keyboard only hits what ever the last thing my mouse clicked or Q and I can't figure out how to have the key only selected a certain button.

I have tried using a focused property and setting it as the default such as                        `enterButton.defaultButtonProperty().bind(enterButton.focusedProperty());`

and I have tried setting it up in scene that when the key code matches the key code of enter it will call the method but it is being treated as a button click and not as key clicked
`scene.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> { if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) { enterButton.fire(); } else{ handleKeyPress(keyEvent.getCode()); } });`

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Have you tried [`EventFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm)?

Comment: Key events are targeted at the node that has focus. And buttons are configured to fire on certain key presses, such as space and--on Windows at least--enter. Also, event _handlers_ (e.g., `onXXX` properties) are invoked during the bubbling phase. That means your on-key-pressed handler, which is registered with the scene, is too late to intercept the method (and might not get invoked anyway given the event might have been consumed). If you want to intercept the key event before it reaches the button, then use an event _filter_, as they're invoked during the capturing phase.

Comment: Call [`setDefaultButton`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#setDefaultButton(boolean)) on the button. *”The default Button is the button that receives a keyboard VK_ENTER press, if no other node in the scene consumes it.”*. You don’t need any binding. If you already tried that and are still having issues, then you need to provide a [mcve] for debugging support.